# Form action display code?

Tags: php, html

I am completely new to php and have written a simple form processing program(from an example in a book) :

```
<!doctype html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bob's</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action = "processorder.php" method = "post" >
<table border = "0">
<tr bgcolor = "#ccc">
    <td width = "150" >Item</td>
    <td width = "15">Quantity</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tires</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="tireqty" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Oil</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="oilqty" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Spark Plugs</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="sparkqty" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit Order" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>


</body>

</html>
```

And :

```
<!doctype html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bob's auto Parts - Order Results</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Bob's Auto Parts</h1>
<h2>Order Results</h2>
<?php
echo '<p>Order processed.</p>';
?>


</body>

</html>
```

When i hit submit on the form the browser then loads to "processorder.php", but displays the actual code. Why is this?

Comment: What do you mean, "displays the actual code?"  The code from processorder.php?  Are you using Apache to serve your files?  Is PHP actually installed?

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. `.php` files are to be processed by servers. Are you running a server? It sounds like you are opening the file directly with your browser.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of PHP is that it runs on the server and **not** the client, and this is for security reasons, dynamic webpage generating, and permanent storage. If you are simply testing this on your laptop on a web browser, it won't work because the computer is not running the PHP software that interprets the PHP code. PHP can only run on a web server that is actually running the proper software. If the client could run PHP, things would not be good because then the client would be able to see data that is meant to be kept safe.

Comment: When i enter http://localhost it returns "It Works", i believe that means i should be able to run php, i am not sure though

Comment: There must be something someone with your PHP configuration then.

Answer (score 0):

May be you were open file with file:// protocol in your browser. You must open your PHP file using any installed web server like XAMPP, Wamp (Windows) or Lamp (Linux) or MAMP (Mac). Install any suitable server and store your files anywhere in root directory.

For Xampp it is C:\xampp\htdocs and for Wamp it is C:\wamp\www is root directory. Before running PHP script don't forget to start apache server from Xampp or Wamp control panel.

Comment: I have mamp installed but i am unsure how to run the apache server there are two checkboxes, one for mysql and one for apache, when i click "start server" the mysql one gets filled in and the apache one stays blank

Comment: Then you should find the problem with apache, confirm apache is started or not. I never seen Mac OS so i can't help with MAMP